# Same table containing different types and different relationships with other tables based on that type

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, diagram

suppose you're recreating the Facebook news feed and would like to have all data for that feed in a table called `Posts`. However, table `Posts` does not include text values only, but can hold `Posts` of type `text`, `notifications`, `images` and `videos`.

Using a single table `Posts` as per the image attached. How can I cleanly define different `Post` types and relate a `Post` of `Image` type to the `Photos` table? Of course **if that post was of type image! There shouldn't be any relationship if the post is of different type. Instead it should relate somewhere else in that case.**

[image: Highlighted Diagram PNG]

I thought about adding an extra field in the `Posts` table such as `Type` of type integer but I don't think that is an elegant solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT
**Important note: The `Photos` table is also used to display images in a photo gallery whether that particular photo is to appear in the newsfeed or not  (table `Posts`), that feature is completely optional.**

Comment: What does this have to do with c# or entity-framework?

Answer (score 0):

1. [Get started with Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ee712907)
2. [Use Code First to an Existing Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620)
3. Create Models For TextPosts, NotificationPosts, ImagePosts and VideoPosts that derive from Posts with appropriate attributes
4. [Deal With the Model Changes using Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542)
5. [Tweak your inheritance mapping strategy to suit your own purposes](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx)